# can't compile c++ netlib 0.11.0 in vs2013

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to get c++ netlib 0.11.0 working with Visual Studio 2013, and I'm having quite a difficult time.  I placed the netlib main folder in my visual studio folder, and I set the include directory properly. You can see this clearly in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQNrA.png

The documentation / examples for c++ netlib tell me that to get started, I need to include

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
```

but when I do this, my compiler can't find anything as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzZ4w.png

Am I supposed to merge the contents of the cpp netlib with the boost library?  I've tried to do that as well but I get a whole other list of problems.  I have no idea how to get this working, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler where you copied Boost.  Project + Properties, C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories setting.  Practice with a "Hello Boost" program.

Comment: Intellisense errors aren't always accurate, try disabling Intellisense errors then compile the program.

Comment: @MarkIngram I did that and I still get the LNK1117 error.  And ideas?  I've added the library directory to the vs properties page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the latest release of Boost and make sure the project's include and library paths are set to include where you installed (and compiled) Boost.

Comment: I did that, and now I'm getting this error: http://i.imgur.com/9rd2gGx.png , any idea?

Comment: It's saying your linker settings are messed up. Ignore the Intellisense warnings, just focus on compiling/linking errors.